# how to dump CSV data into postgresql table using python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have CSV file whose data i need to dump into postgresql table using python script.Also need to create a dynamic table in postrgresql.

Help me if know any ready made tool or the conventional way .

Regards,

Comment: take a look at COPY command

Answer (score 2):

`psycopg2` offers support for the `COPY` command, which is what you'll want to use.

See [Using `COPY` in the `psycopg2` docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). You'll want to use `COPY ... WITH (FORMAT CSV)`.